# Update DynamoDB item with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have this item:

```
{
 "name": "jon",
 "id": "001",
 "age": 17
}
```

And I want update a specific attribute (age), I'm trying with this:

```
dynamodb.update({
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Key": {
            "id": id
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "set age = :a",
            "ExpressionAttributesValues":{
                ":a":20
            },
        "ReturnValues":"UPDATED_NEW"
            }, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
              context.fail(err);
        else
            context.fail(data);
});
```

I'm getting an error, but I had follow the doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.03

I think it must be a syntax error, but I can't find it.

Comment: Please don't post questions like this without including the actual error message as part of your question.

Comment: Lambda doesnt give to me an error, just say that it could not execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your error message is, but I notice that you are calling context.fail(data) if there is no error. Replace this by context.succeed(data)